# Excel VBA DoEvents on multiple computers with different processing power

Tags: vba, excel

It's quite common that a file I have worked on will be used on multiple computers. The computers will not have the same processing power, but I would hope to keep the "experience" consistent.The code below will trigger when someone has made a selection from a listbox. The textbox will flash green and then return back to the original color. On PC1 this occurs at a very pleasing speed, however on PC2, it occurs at twice the speed I intended. Is there a way to somehow slowdown/speed up the events (Most likely the `Sleep` call) when they are happening too fast/slow? It's clear I don't have the best grasp on DoEvents, but I would appreciate any comments. Thanks

PC1: i5-2520M 2.50Ghz / 8GM RAM

PC2: i7-6700K 4.0Ghz / 16 GB RAM

```
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub flashSelection

Dim i As Integer

'Set Color First
Me.TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(220, 220, 220)

For i = 1 To 22
    Me.TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(220 - (i * 10), 220 - (i * 2), 220 - (i * 10))
    DoEvents
    Call Sleep(0.55)
Next i
For i = 1 To 22
    Me.TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0 + (i * 10), 176 + (i * 2), 0 + (i * 10))
    DoEvents
    Call Sleep(0.55)
Next i

'Reset Color
Me.TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(220, 220, 220)

End If
```

Comment: In my opinion, if you're looking for a rich UI experience, messing with UserForm objects like this will just frustrate you. If you have some web dev experience, a nice option may be to create a task pane add-in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-overview

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for your reply. I am actually intrigued by your comment. I have been pushing VBA very hard lately, using windows API functions etc.. I think it's time to start branching out.

Comment: Glad to hear it :) it's definitely more involved than just hitting `Alt+F11` and whipping up a userform, but you can make a really nice UI with the new task pane add-ins. Check out this sample from OfficeDev on github: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-WoodGrove-Expense-Trends

Comment: Take a look at one of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48266194/5781745). You will see that `sleep ##` isn't actually sleeping for how long you tell it to.